# Why does a wave composed of two waves have an FFT with only one peak?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, wave, decomposition

I am trying to find a value from a given mathematical function whose input is supposed to be derived from FFT components. Essentially, I follow the procedure from [1] which assumes that a given sine wave (regular wave) is composed of a cosine and sine wave of different amplitude but the same frequency.

How can I find the amplitudes of each decomposed wave if the FFT shows just one peak at the wave frequency?

The signal is a regular sine wave superimposed with 2 waves traveling in the opposite direction. We have two singals (i.e. two measurment devices)  whose components are required for the mathemtical equation. So,

> **Signal<sub>1</sub>* = Wave<sub>1</sub> + Wave<sub>2</sub> = a<sub>1</sub>cos(*kx-ft+e<sub>1</sub>*) +
> a<sub>2</sub>cos(kx+ft+e<sub>2</sub>) = A<sub>1</sub>cos(ft) + B<sub>1</sub>sin(ft)*
>
> **Signal<sub>2</sub>* = Wave<sub>1</sub> + Wave<sub>2</sub> = a<sub>1</sub>cos(*kx-ft+e<sub>1</sub>*) +
> a<sub>2</sub>cos(kx+ft+e<sub>2</sub>) = A<sub>2</sub>cos(ft) + B<sub>2</sub>sin(ft)*
> where,
>
> - *a* = ampltiude
> - *k* = wavenumber
> - *f* = frequency
> - *e* = phase
> - *t* = time

The paper states *A<sub>1</sub>,A<sub>2</sub> ,B<sub>1</sub>  and A<sub>2</sub>*  can be estimated through Fourier Analysis to be plugged into a equation.

---

[1] [Yoshimi Goda, Yasumasa Suzuki, "Estimation of Incident and Reflected Waves in Random Wave Experiments", Coastal Engineering 1976 -1977](https://doi.org/10.1061/9780872620834.048)

Comment: Hint: $e^{jx}=?$ You know a formula for this!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a completely new to this. A direct answer would be most helpful.

Comment: Euler's equation ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the cited article is not accessible (behind a paywall). Is it really true that it describes a "sine wave [...] [to be] composed of a cosine and a sine wave"? Or is it a _complex_ wave that's composed of a cosine and a sine?

Comment: @applesoup     Essentially, a given signal which is a regular sin/cos wave is composed of two superposed waves: Wave = Wave1 + Wave2 = a1*cos(x-ft+e1) + a2*cos(x+ft+e2) = Acos(ft) + Bsin(ft). The paper states that A and B can be derived from FFT to be plugged in another equation.

Comment: @user244717, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generalized form $Ae^{j\theta}$ with $A$ and $\theta$ as real numbers is a phasor with magnitude $K$ and angle $\theta$. A "positive" frequency $\Omega_o$ is such a phasor with constant magnitude $A$ and rotating counter-clockwise with angle that increases linearly with time as $\Omega_o t$. (And similarly a negative frequency would be rotating clock-wise). The real and imaginary components of such a single frequency tone would be given as $\cos(\Omega_o t)$ and $\sin(\Omega_o t)$ respectively which is Euler's formula. Therefore any such "single tone" $Ae^{j\Omega_o t}$ would have cosine and sine components. The Discrete Fourier Transform is composed of such "single tones" with each bin represented in the time domain as $Ae^{j k \omega_o n}$, where $\omega_o = 2\pi/N$.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I'm beginning to understand. So in my case, The amplitude signal from my FFT is single tone and I can split it into the sine and cosine wave components as 'A(cos(Ωt) + j sin(Ωt) )'?

Comment: Yes - in Signal Processing I find it easier to conceptualize a single frequency as a single phasor rotating on the complex plane rather than sines and cosines which each phaser consists of. A single sinusoidal waveform has two such rotating phasors so in my abstraction consists of two single frequencies: a positive frequency and a negative frequency. The is given by $2\cos(x)=e^{jx}+e^{-jx}$

Comment: In that case, wouldn't the amplitudes of these two phasor components be equal, since the only difference is the phase?  Also going back to the original question, the goal is to derive Ycos(xt) +Zsin(xt) from a sine wave, from what I understood Y= A (FFT signal) and B = Ai ?

Comment: In which case? If you are referring to a cosine then yes they have equal amplitude and opposite phase. To derive Ycos(xt) + Zsin(xt) from Asin(xt+ phi) I assume you mean which is really nothing specific to an FFT but a simple trig identitiy, as listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20trigonometric%20identities%20are,of%20one%20or%20more%20angles.

Comment: maybe if I show the equation like how I did for the other commenter. The signal is a wave which can be , according to the literature, defined as : Wave = Wave1 + Wave2 = a1*cos(x-ft+e1) + a2*cos(x+ft+e2) = Acos(ft) + Bsin(ft). I have the Wave signal and need to find A and B. From your answer, I assumed A = amp(Wave) and B = j * amp(Wave).

Comment: Your original question was about the FFT (or in general the Discrete Fourier Transform) which returns a complex result and thus each bin has a magnitude and phase and therefore can be expressed in terms of cosine and sine components on the real and imaginary axis of the complex plane per my answer.

Comment: I understand. However, is that the right approach when considering the above formula, or would the trig function (with A taken from FFT) work better?

Comment: Could you write out the complete equation, perhaps with an actual example, or otherwise if variable based with the very concise math, at the bottom of your original question and then show there where you are stuck? I think that will make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited the question as per your recommendation.

Comment: Ok I see- yes if you get a single tone from the FFT it will be a complex value and the the cosine term A1 is the real component and the B1 term is the imaginary component and ft is related to the bin number. You would also want to normalize the FFT by dividing by the total number of samples, but that depends on the specific FFT algorithm used.